# Right implementation choice for switching 20+ different screens

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, implementation

I'm making a quiz-like game, where user answers each question before they are allowed to go to the next one.

Characteristics of my app:

- Each session will have
  around 10-30 screens.
- In general, the screens are heterogenious in layout
  structures, but they can be
  classified into 5-6 types.
- The expected time that user interacts with each screen is 10-30
  seconds
- Once user goes to the next screen,
  the previous one is not needed
  anymore (he never goes back)
- I want to have a nice sliding
  transition animation when going from
  one screen to the next

Implementations I'm considering:

1. Start a new `Activity` for each
   screen in the 'forwarding' style,
   i.e. start the next screen then
   finish the current one.
2. Load all the views before hand and
   use `ViewAnimator`

It looks like none of my current solution is good. Can you help me on a solution that is good in terms of memory consumption, battery consumption, and responsiveness?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the problem with ViewAnimator?

Comment: How do get the animations when say, I re-use the same View and change the content? If I don't re-use the screens, memory consumption maybe too large. I may have to keep 20+ screens around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK below is what I did. It turned out I manually set the animation

```
onCreate() {
    mAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_in_right);
    mViewPool = new View[] { /* A few views for re-using, each of different type */ };
}

proceed() {
    nextView = getView(type);
    mFrame.removeAllChilds();
    mFrame.addView(nextView);
    nextView.startAnimation(mAnimation);
}

getView(int type) {
    View view = mViewPool[type];
    // reset some subviews if neccessary
    return view;
}
```

Where `mFrame` is whatever ViewGroup you think is appropriate, not neccessarily `ViewAnimator`. Mine happens to be `ScrollView`.

If you see any potential problem with this approach, please let me know. Many thanks.